# Why can this script running in the background survive `kill` and termination of the invoking shell?

Tags: bash, scripting, process, kill, background-process

I have a script

```
$ cat PDFX.sh 
#! /bin/bash
wine /home/t/pdfxcview/PDFXCview.exe
```

In an interactive bash shell, I run

```
$ ./PDFX.sh &
[1] 21740
```

and then try to kill it

```
$ kill $(jobs -p)
[1]+  Terminated              ./PDFX.sh
```

It says "Terminated", but the program `PDFXCview.exe` is still running without being affected, and it can even survive after I exit the shell

```
$ exit
```

- If I replace `wine /home/t/pdfxcview/PDFXCview.exe` in the script with `evince`, it won't survive the `kill` command and the termination of the shell.
- if I run `wine /home/t/pdfxcview/PDFXCview.exe &` directly in the interactive bash shell, it  won't survive the `kill` command and the termination of the shell.

I was wondering why the difference?

I don't think there is something special about `wine`.

Comment: The shell process died but `wine` ignores the signal?

Comment: I guess yes.....

Comment: Or wine forked off a process?

Answer (score 3):

Running

```
wine /home/t/pdfxcview/PDFXCview.exe
```

will normally result in a number of processes starting up, to provide the typical Windows environment a Windows binary expects (`explorer.exe` etc.). Wine starts all these processes via `wineserver`, and detaches them all — so they are not children of your shell, nor even of `wineserver`. The binary you asked Wine to run can be a child process of the shell, but it’s also disowned so that it can outlive its parent. Exiting the shell from which you started all these processes doesn’t affect them.

To kill a Windows program, you need to find its pid and kill that directly. You can kill *all* Wine processes with `wineserver -k`.

When you run `PDFX.sh &`, a new shell is started to process the script, and that shell runs Wine to start `PDFXCview.exe`. When you run `kill %1`, you’re killing the shell running the script, not the Wine process. The Wine process continues running (re-parented to pid 1).

When you run `wine /home/t/pdfxcview/PDFXCview.exe &`, the Wine process is started directly. When you then run `kill %1`, you’re killing the Wine process, which stops the Windows program. If no other Windows program is running, `wineserver` should terminate shortly thereafter.

Comment: Thanks. If I run `wine /home/t/pdfxcview/PDFXCview.exe &` directly in the interactive bash shell, it won't survive the kill command and the termination of the shell. Why the difference?

Comment: By "your second example", do you mean  running `wine /home/t/pdfxcview/PDFXCview.exe &` directly in the interactive bash shell? In the original example where I run `./PDFX.sh &` in an interactive bash shell,  what does the shell job correspond to, and what does `kill %1` kill?

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it if you could take  a chance at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446387/why-does-the-termination-of-a-noninteractive-bash-process-affect-or-not-affect-i?