# Why does the termination of a noninteractive bash process affect or not affect its child process, when running a script?

Tags: bash, process

I have a bash script `script1`:

```
#! /bin/bash
evince
```

and another script `script2`

```
#! /bin/bash
evince &
```

When I run

```
./script2
```

the bash process exits immediately after putting `evince` into background, leaving the `evince` process continue running.

When I run

```
./script1 &
```

the bash process waits for `evince` to finish running.

If I `kill` the bash process, the bash process exits and also terminates the `evince` process.

I was wondering why the termination of the bash process doesn't affect the `evince` process in the second script, but does in the first script?

Could you explain in terms of system calls such as `fork(), exit()` and `wait()`?

Thanks.

This is related to [Why can this script running in the background survive `kill` and termination of the invoking shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441967/why-can-this-script-running-in-the-background-survive-kill-and-termination-of), but here I want to learn the basic general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did really only kill the shell, you should make a bug report against bash.

Since modern shells automatically enable job control for interactive shells,

```
./script1&
```

creates a new job with an own process group id.

The shell waits on the program `evince` and if you call:

```
kill -9 $!
```

only the shell will be killed and `evince` will continue to run.

If you however call:

```
kill %1
```

This kills the whole job including `evince`.